# Compiler Design storage allocation for currying

Tags: memory-management, compiler-construction, computer-science

I need the full explanation for this statement:

"Programming languages which permit a function to return a function as its result cannot be implemented with a stack-based storage allocation scheme for activation records."

My questions:

1. Why cannot they be implemented like that?
2. How can then they be implemented?

I understand that creating a dynamic link or returning a memory address to the function will not do the trick as it is not a variable that stores some value.

Please give a detailed explanation of the Data Structure or allocation method used with the implementation details.

Further reading references are totally helpful.

This was given as a true option in GATE 2008 exam. The answer was not explained. I need the reasoning as to why is it right.

Comment: Sounds contrived to me. Functions routinely return pointers to newly allocated memory that the caller must know how to dispose of. This memory could be used for code, or not (though the more common scenario is returning a function _pointer_, not an actual executable image). But, what's the problem with either?

Comment: When you quote a statement, you should provide a credit (a link if possible,  or a bibliography entry if it's dead trees). If it's a textbook, lots of people here probably have it or have access to it, so the bib entry is still useful. Knowing the source makes it much easier to explain in context.

Comment: Also, this question probably belongs on [cs.se]

Comment: It was asked in GATE exam. This was an option as a true statement. No explanation was given as to why is it true.

Comment: Consider the fact that Go has first class functions and closures, yet uses a stack-based allocation scheme.  It also has heap-based allocation, and chooses the correct allocation at compile time. Furthermore, goroutine stacks are GC-able: https://golang.org/src/runtime/stack.go In the end, I think the only way to answer this is [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)).